# Output string from table

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of groups from a user in my AD, but the out put looks like:
`@{name=Domain Users}`
I am exporting to a csv file and it outputs that.

```
Write-Host "Checking for CSV folder at $CSVpath"
if (!(Test-Path $CSVpath))
{
    write-host "File path not found creating..."
    New-Item -Path $CSVpath -Force -ItemType Directory
}

write-host "Checking $user groups..."
$usergroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership TEST.USER | select name 
write-host $usergroups

try
{
    $usergroups | Export-Csv -Path "$CSVPath\\$user.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
catch
{
    Write-Error "Failed to export csv: $Error"
    pause
    Exit-PSSession
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: `select name` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `name` field of the object `$usergroups`

so `$usergroups.name`